# Handling the window folder path using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, directory, window

I have a window folder path, example:

```js
var text1 = "C:\Mine\2020\example.txt"
```

But when I print `text1` to console, the result: `"C:Mine‚0example.txt"`

Note: `text1` is information from another place. The above case is just an example.

I tried:

```js
String.raw`${text1}`
```

The result is still: `"C:Mine‚0example.txt"`

Only when:

```js
String.raw`C:\Mine\2020\example.txt`
```

The result is exactly what I need: `"C:\Mine\2020\example.txt"`

But my input is `text1` variable. Is there any way to handle the `text1` variable? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try this

**Test code**

```
const filePath = String.raw `C:\Mine\2020\example.txt`;
```

console.log(`The file was uploaded from: ${filePath}`);

**result**
The file was uploaded from: C:\Mine\2020\example.txt

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

Comment: I have read this document before, but What I need is a way to handle the `text1` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Escape characters my friend.

var text1 = "C:\Mine\2020\example.txt"

Test Code used
{

```
var text1 = "C:\\Mine\\2020\\example.txt";
alert(text1);
```

}

Result
{

```
 C:\Mine\2020\example.txt
```

}

If you are unsure about escape characters check the below link.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: Thank for your help. I know escape characters, but `text1` variables are required as above question.

Comment: Does this help, it retains the normal string and makes it so you can edit the string as well as out put the string as normal without the escape characters?



let text1 = String.raw `C:\Mine\2020\example.txt`;

alert(text1);

text1 = String.raw `C:\Mine\2020\Changable.txt`;

alert(text1);

Comment: Please treat `text1` as information obtained from another place and you cannot use it directly

Comment: Ok i dont think its possible, you need to explain how you are getting the data into javascript.

Comment: for example the "C:\Mine" the interpreter in javascript converts \M i think it converts it to \null and makes it null and blank etc and i dont think you can stop it from doing that before runtime of the interpreter for javascript. but there might be a solution pending on how you are getting the data and might be able to do it in a Safeway aka encoding or some method.

Comment: Hmm, so javascript has no direct handling and must go through pretreatment

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's useful

```
var text1 = "C:\\Mine\\2020\\example.txt"
console.log(text1)
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I know escape characters, but `text1` variables are required as above question.